# border-radius for specific element not rendered in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, curve

Here is my site:
http://splash.inting.org/wp/

On the right sidebar, I have two elements, the reg form on top and the small slider at the bottom. Both have the same border-radius styles implemented but the one in the bottom does not have the curved borders rendered in Chrome. I already applied overflow: hidden.

Things to take note:

1. both elements (registration and slider) have same border-radius styles
   applied but in chrome, only the registration is rendered with correct border styles
2. the border-radius renders correctly in firefox and even in IE

Any ideas? Thanks!

**CHROME:**

[image]

**FIREFOX:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the border radius directly to the image.

```
.meteor-slides .mslide img
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that since not all sidebar elements will have images. But if that's the only work around I will try it. I'll give some feedback once I get it done. Thanks @MLM!

Comment: @AnimaSola If it is other kind of content then the border-radius on the parent should take care of it. So they will work in conjunction.